# Personalizar estilo de Textbox

Tags: html, css

¿Se puede quitar esta barra u ocultarla de la linea del textbox ? o no ?

[image: Barra titilante]

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas barra?

Comment: En el textbox, la linea/barrita que parpadea, cuando colocas el texto, hay alguna forma de ocultarlo mediante CSS o no ?

Comment: Mira esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457976/9609518

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza este estilo en tu input

```html
<input type="text" style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;"/>
```

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el color azul en el borde

Comment: @JheymanMejia en que momento el OP habla sobre el borde azul. Solo pregunta si es posible quitar el cursor.

Comment: Utiliza esto input:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa tienes razón, confundí la pregunta, disculpas